# Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 Build SQLCMD Post Deployment Script to Dacpac

Tags: visual-studio, deployment, tfs, msbuild, azure-pipelines

In lower version of Visual Studio, we have post deployment script (Script.PostDeployment.sql) to contain a list of SQLCMD mode scripts -

```
:r .\LookupTableData\dbo.SQLCMD1.sql
:r .\LookupTableData\dbo.SQLCMD2.sql
:r .\LookupTableData\dbo.SQLCMD3.sql
:r .\LookupTableData\dbo.SQLCMD4.sql
```

In vNext TFS, how to set up task "Visual Studio Build" in a solution to contain Script.PostDeployment.sql in a database project and build it into a DACPAC file, so the lookup data can be deployed like tables, stored procedures, and others?

Comment: Could you  enable SQLCMD mode from inside a batch script or powershell script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the Post Deployment script can’t be included in Dacpac file, you can check [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/05a23da2-4f99-4f81-a14f-23ea715c1228/dacpac-deployment-with-pre-and-post-deployment-scirpt?forum=vstsdb) related thread.

There are many [extensions](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=sql&target=VSTS&sortBy=Relevance) in the Marketplace that include run SQL scripts task, so you can run SQL script after deploying database to your server, such as SQL Toolkit.

Comment: but the TFS 2015 build only generates a single .dacpac file.  My post deployment scripts are not delivered to the linked build folder.  How can I get these scripts to execute?  Is there a parameter in MSBuild to specify this in Visual Studio Build task?

Comment: @Don You can put script in the sql file (.sql), then specify this file in build definition. It deploys dacpac file, then run scripts, so you can't specify parameter in MSBuild.